# Ubuntu 14.04 screen lock policy

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen, screensaver, policy

We have a security policy that the Ubuntu desktops have to lock the screen after 10 minutes.I use to use xscreensaver on Ubuntu 12.04 for this by removing gnome-screensaver and overwriting the config file for xscreensaver encase someone was to change it. This no longer works now that the Unity lock is taking over xscreensaver. Please help